# Photosynthesis relation to work function and photoionization

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, biophysics, photoelectric-effect

When photosynthetic organism’s use pigments such as chlorophyll, the metal ion in the center emits an electron after absorbing a specific wavelength of light, at 400-700 nm
This does not make sense to me, as magnesium, the metal ion in Chlorophyll, has a work function of 3.66 eV and a photoionization energy of 7.6 eV.
Meanwhile it emits an electron after receiving incident light less than 3 eV in energy.
How is this possible?